# Running a bash script combining Fortran and Mathemtica scripts

Tags: macos, bash, fortran, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to run a bash script (on Mac) which combines a Fortran program with a Mathemtica script (Code in the following).

In a nutshell, what it does is: I run `Adding_ns.m` and it creates a new file named `points.dat`. Then the length of this file, `$NUM`, will be used as a variable in `./pebblegame.e $NUM points.dat > pebbled.dat` (applying a Fortran program on the file) to create `pebbled.dat`. Then in the next loop, `Adding_ns.m` uses the existing `points.dat` and `pebbled.dat` to create new ones.

```
#!/bin/bash
BD='MyDirectory'

for ((i=1; i<20; i++)); do

 /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -script Adding_ns.m

 NUM=$(grep -c "." points.dat)
 echo 'Length points is' $NUM

 ./pebblegame.e $NUM points.dat > pebbled.dat

 LEN=$(grep -c "." pebbled.dat)
 CRIT=$(echo $LEN/3072 | bc -l)
 echo 'Criterion is' $CRIT

done
exit
```

The puzzling part is when I run the codes manually (I mean type commands in terminal) in the same order, it works fine but when I use `For` loop, it only returns the first result correctly This convinces me that problem is with my BASH script.

Since finally I need to loop 20000 times, I need to do this automatically.

Comment: Try running it with `bash -x` and seeing where it stops. Don't think the issues is with the for loop.

Comment: What is the `grep -c "."` trying to count?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: It is supposed to return number of lines in the file.

Comment: Try replacing it with `NUM=$(wc -l < file)`

Comment: Other than that, I would suggest adding a `sleep 2` after the Mathematica invocation, and also after the `pebblegame` invocation in case there are timing/flushing issues. Also, as @BroSlow suggested, change your first line to `#!/bin/bash  -xv` so you can see lines as they are executed.

Comment: why dont you implement the loop & call fortran in mathematica?

Comment: Do you need to recalculate points.dat *inside* the loop, or should you do it once before entering the loop?

Comment: @george: That would be great if you can refer me to a reference since I didn't know I can do that!

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes I need to recalculate it each time to re-import into Fortran and Mathematica scripts.

Comment: Why do you use grep to count something in points.dat ? You can easily produce in your Mathematica code another file or a first comment line or whatever giving this count ?

Comment: Have you estimated the time it would take to recode the fortran in Mathematica ?

Comment: @ogerard:The fortran program was written two decades ago (not by me and it took one year) and I have done another bash script combining mathematica and fortran successfully.

Comment: @ogerard: I have to do grep within bash since I need to pass the count to Fortran program.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: `wc -l` gives the wrong value (one less).

Comment: I can't imagine any way `wc -l` can give the wrong number of lines in a file - it has been used in millions of shell scripts for the last 30+ years.

Comment: Did you put in the `bash -xv` and the two `sleep`s I suggested? What was the output?

Comment: @Mehdi : you don't need to count with grep, you only need to transmit the count. And Mathematica can do it by writing a small file with only the number or as a .sh file with something like export POINTS=234, or a few other ways.